# what conditions on the positive integer $ \ a \ $ imply that the radius of convergence of the power series would be $ \ 1 \ $?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the binomial function or infinite series $ \ B_a(x)=(1+x)^a=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\large a(a-1)(a-2) \cdots \cdots (a-n+1)}{\large n!}x^n$.

(i) Under what conditions on the positive integer $ \ a \ $, the radius of convergence of the power series would be $ \ 1 \ $ ?

**Answer:**

(i)

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence.

The $n^{th}$ term of the series is $ b_n=\frac{\large a(a-1)(a-2) \cdots \cdots (a-n+1)}{\large n!}$.

Now by ratio test,

$R =1 \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1 \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a(a-1)(a-2) \cdots (a-n+1)(a-n)}{(n+1)!} \times \frac{n!}{a(a-1)(a-2) \cdots (a-n+1)}=1 \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a-n}{n+1} =1 \\  $

What would be the value of $ \ a $ from the last equation?

Is there any option so that $R$=radius of convergence$=1$ ?

Help me

Comment: If $a\in \Bbb Z^+$ or $a=0$ then the co-efficient of $x^n$ is  $ 0 $ for alll $n\geq a+1$ and the series is actually just a polynomial, the  classical Binomial  Theorem expansion, valid for all $x.$.... Otherwise the radius of convergence is $1.$ This is Newton's Generalized Binomial Theorem... BTW the way you have written the series (just before "(i)" ) is ok for $n>0$ but not for the term with $n=0$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I did not get you. when the radius of convergence will be  $ \ 1 \ $? Please do a more explicitly

Comment: As you have worked out by the Ratio Test (although you left out some  absolute-value symbols) if  no $b_n$ is $0$  then  $|b_{n+1}/b_n|\to 1$  no matter what $a$ is.  That implies the radius is $1$  regardless of the value of $a$, provided that no $b_n$ is $0.$ The condition that no $b_n$ is $ 0$ is equivalent  to $a$ being anything except a non-negative integer.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Than you very much

Comment: Suggested reading: The Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula. (See wikipedia).  Although when there are factorials within the expressions for the co-efficients, you often need Stirling's Formula (for approximate values of factorials) in order to use the C-H formula to find the radius.